# How long will it take to regain my fitness?

Tags: running, running-training-plan

I've had to stop running due to an injury that wasn't related to running. When I stopped I was able to do a 3 mile run on a track in 19 minutes and 5 seconds. This was in late July. I'm getting back into it now, and I did a 24 minute 3 mile run.

Will it take as long as I had to train initially to get back to where I was and also can I return to my former weekly mileage at a slower pace or do I need to build back up again?

Comment: @JohnP how is this a duplicate of the linked question, and how do any of the answers given there address what user32123 wants to know?

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger - I misread at the time, however this really isn't a great fit. This is a "I" question, that nobody can really answer except with a lot of personal stories. That's not a good model for a stack question.

Comment: @JohnP I agree. I gave my advice and I think it's consistent with the duplicate post that had been linked but in the end it's just my opinion from my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my own experience, you should be back in about a month. First week will be rough but you will start seeing improvement by the end of week 2. Take your time, you will get everything back and it won't take long.

Definitely build back the mileage and make sure you give your body enough time to recover. If you ran 10 miles on Sundays, I would do 4 miles on week 1, 6 week 2, 8 week 3 and 10 on week 4. Adjust mid-week runs accordingly, taking extra rest days in the first 2 weeks.

Comment: Good luck! When you get back in shape, you will appreciate what you have achieved and will get extra satisfaction from the effort you put in. You will get there, enjoy the journey.